# MonoTouch: Can't create DbParameterCollection?

Tags: c#, ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios, system.data

I'm a vb.net guy trying to figure out MonoTouch c#.

I made this data helper:

```
public static void ExecuteCommand (SqliteConnection cnn, string command, System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection parameters)
{
    using (var c = cnn.CreateCommand()) {
        c.CommandText = command;
        c.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        foreach (var p in parameters)
        {
            c.Parameters.Add (p);
        }
        c.ExecuteNonQuery ();
    }
}
```

And now I want to call the ExecuteCommand...

```
var parameters = new System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection();
parameters.Add("@1", DbType.String).Value = "test";
DataConnection.ExecuteCommand ("INSERT INTO mytest (name) VALUES (@)", parameters);
```

But MonoTouch says...

- var parameters = new System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection(); *<-- "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection'"*
- parameters.Add("@1", DbType.String).Value = "test"; *<-- "A local variable 'parameters' cannot be used before it is declared."*

I'm sure the answer is pretty easy, but comming from a VB.Net world, this is not obvious to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparametercollection.aspx) is **abstract** as such you cannot create it. You should be creating a (concrete( collection that inherits from it. In SQLite case it would be `Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteParameterCollection`.

Your second error is likely related to the first, since `parameters` could not be compiled correctly.